# Webtoon where someone is betrayed and reincarnated

Tags: story-identification, reincarnation

I'm looking for a webtoon were the guy gets betrayed by his friend. And get reincarnated. Before he reincarnated I think he was a swordman and then changed it to a mage and found out his dad is trying to kill him

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.